# Please solve its function issue

Tags: python

remove  the error of this question plzz

```
def my_patt(n =int(input("Enter patte.. row ")),stop):
    start = 1
    stop = 2

    currentNumber = stop

    for row in range(currentNumber, n+2):
        for col in range(start, stop):
            currentNumber -= 1
            print(currentNumber, end="  ")
        
        print("")
        start = stop
        stop += row
        currentNumber = stop

my_patt()
```

Comment: Move the `n = int(input(...` part *inside* the function, not in the declaration.

Comment: Please, fix the formatting of your code block. I tried to fix the indentation, but it is unclear where the function ends. Check [ask].

Comment: Also describe what the function is supposed to do and provide an example of input/output

Answer (score 0):

There is unfortunately several errors in this code.

1. you should put input as the function parameter's default.
2. When you say start = 1, stop = 2 in the function it is local so you won't affect the actual variable outside of the function.
3. Not really an error, but your print statement basically does nothing.
4. And be careful with the indentation

Here is my attempt on fixing this:

```
def my_patt(start, stop):
    start = 1
    stop = 2
    return start, stop

stop  = 10
currentNumber = stop
n = 10

for row in range(currentNumber, n+2):
    for col in range(start, stop):
        currentNumber -= 1
        print(currentNumber)

start = stop
currentNumber = stop

start, stop = my_patt(start, stop)
```

I'm not sure if I fixed your code since I wasn't sure what everything was doing, but if there are any problems please let me know :)

Comment: ok sure  cozy code

Comment: its giving error start is not defined ........ solve plese

Comment: which line is the error in